# what is the use of " ApexPages.StandardSetController" and when we should write it

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class OpportunitiesPaginationController{
    Public Integer size{get;set;} 
    Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;} 
    public List<SelectOption> paginationSizeOptions{get;set;}

    public OpportunitiesPaginationController(){
        size=10;
        paginationSizeOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('5','5'));
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('10','10'));
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('20','20'));
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('50','50'));
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('100','100'));
    }

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get {
            if(setCon == null) {                
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                      [select id,Name,AccountId,Account.name,Amount,StageName,CloseDate,LastModifiedDate from Opportunity]));
                setCon.setPageSize(size);  
                noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
            }            
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }

    //Changes the size of pagination
    public PageReference refreshPageSize() {
         setCon.setPageSize(size);
         return null;
    }

    // Initialize setCon and return a list of record    

    public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
         return (List<Opportunity>) setCon.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that you need after reading the manual?

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce has following types of standard controllers which we can use and extend:

1. Standard Controller:

   - Handle for single record.
   - Has all same features in standard new, edit and view pages.
2. Standard List Controller:

   - Handles multiple record.
   - uses Standard List Controller with use of `recordSetVar` attribute in the page.
   - Quoting from Use [Standard List Controllers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/units/visualforce_standard_list_controllers) trailhead module:

     > Using a standard list controller is very similar to using a standard
     >   controller. First you set the standardController attribute on the
     >    component, then you set the recordSetVar attribute on the
     >   same component. The standardController attribute sets the object to
     >   work with, just like with the standard controller. The recordSetVar
     >   sets the name of the variable to be created with the collection of
     >   records, here, {! contacts }. By convention, this variable is usually
     >   named the plural of the object name.
3. [Standard Set Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) (using apex):

   - Handles multiple record.
   - used to extend/mimic List view feature using a controller  List controller.

     > StandardSetController objects allow you to create list controllers
     >   similar to, or as extensions of, the pre-built Visualforce list
     >   controllers provided by Salesforce.

---

This is how a Standard List Controller look like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">
    <!-- Your code -->
</apex:page>
```

---

StandardSetController is used to extend List controller with apex. For that we need to create controller having a property of type `ApexPages.StandardSetController`, which can be instantiated using a `query` or `query locator` (thats because it has 2 different type of [StandardSetController Constructor's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_constructors.htm)).

Salesforce has defined couple of [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm) (like Cancel, First, Last, etc.) in `StandardSetController` class, using which we can use some OOTB functionalties.

Now when you pass the data to StandardSetController, with those implemented methods described above, it can manage the data in the list.

Common example of using a standard set controller is when you need to have checkboxes for selection of each record.

**Added:** Please feel free to correct if there are any mistakes in my understanding. :)